# how to extract specific message from a line with bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

my file contains lines like that

```
aaa bbb ccc {"eee": "ggg", "mmm": "sss"}
aaa1 bbb1 {"eee": "ggg"}
aaa2 bbb2 ccc2 
aaa3 bbb3 ccc3 {"eee": "ggg", "mmm": "sss"}
```

I want to extract from each line the mesage between `{}`. If there is no message between `{}` then return empty message.

How to do that in bash?

Comment: by `return empty message` do you mean empty line or nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try awk-

```
$cat file
aaa bbb ccc {"eee": "ggg", "mmm": "sss"}
aaa1 bbb1 {"eee": "ggg"}
aaa2 bbb2 ccc2 
aaa3 bbb3 ccc3 {"eee": "ggg", "mmm": "sss"}

$awk -F[{}]  '{print $2}' file

Output-
"eee": "ggg", "mmm": "sss"
"eee": "ggg"

"eee": "ggg", "mmm": "sss"
```

This command sets the delimiters to be the curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

If your `grep` supports positive and negative look arounds:

```
grep -oP '(?<={).*(?=})' inputfile
"eee": "ggg", "mmm": "sss"
"eee": "ggg"
"eee": "ggg", "mmm": "sss"
```

This will check anything in between `{` and `}` . Which is equal to `.*?` and its non-greedy.

Comment: can be simplified to `grep -oP '{\K[^}]+'`